# How to Disable Resize in CKEditor and Change Language to English in php?

Tags: php, ckeditor

i want to  disable resizing ckeditor in php and its default language to english change .

i've loaded the ckeditor in php below :

```
<?php
     $CKeditor = new CKeditor();
     $CKeditor->BasePath = 'ckeditor/';
     $CKeditor->editor('editor1');
?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$config['language']='en';
$config['removePlugins']='resize';   //Remove resize image
$config['resize_enabled ']=false;   //Disallow resizing
```

And initialize CKeditor like:

```
$CKeditor->editor("editor1",'',$config);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's dedicated configuration option [`config.resize_enabled`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-resize_enabled) to control the resizer. As for the language, you can set it with [`config.language`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-language).